# How to lower message height of MaterialAlertDialog

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles

I'm trying to use MaterialAlertDialogBuilder to create a MaterialAlertDailog.
I manage to control most of the attributes of the dialog in styles.xml except for the space between the message and the OK button.

[image: sample]

I'm currently using this dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


    <style name="MaterialDialogDark" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/material_dialog_background_color_dark</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/MaterialAlert.Button.Dark</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/MaterialAlert.Button.Dark</item>
        <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/MaterialAlert.Body.Dark</item>
        <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/MaterialAlert.Title.Dark</item>
        <item name="materialAlertDialogTitlePanelStyle">@style/MaterialAlert.Panel</item>
    </style>


    <style name="MaterialAlert.Panel" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Panel">

        <item name="android:layout_height">90dp</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MaterialAlert.Button.Dark" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_dialog_btn_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MaterialAlert.Body.Dark" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_dialog_body_color</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
        <item name="android:lines">5</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.1</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">none</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MaterialAlert.Title.Dark" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_dialog_title_color_dark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
findViewById(R.id.testDialog).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this ,R.style.MaterialDialogDark)
                        .setTitle(R.string.label_title)
                        .setMessage(R.string.label_not_enough_points)

                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,(dialogInterface, i) -> {})
                        .show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Probably the problem is at MaterialAlert.Body.Dark: `<item name="android:lines">5</item>`

Comment: You are right! but now I have a different problem, I have several messages (several scenarios) which has different number of rows. If I will remove the lines attribute I will see only the first row. Can it be wrap_content somehow regardless of how many rows I have?

Comment: Looking at [Material Styles](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/dialog/res/values/styles.xml), I think that `<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>` should work, but I've never tried it.

Comment: I have that line in my styles (MaterialAlert.Body.Dark) but it seems the textview ignores it or I have a problem with a different style attribute

Comment: Perhaps `<item name="android:singleLine">false</item>` is messing up with it?

Comment: No, still one line. I added this line because I think by default it's single line.
Even if I will include \n it will ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there is no an easy fix (at least from play around with the styles.xml) At the end I created a custom layout (which has only a textview) and then it worked as it should.

**custom_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/material_dialog_body_color"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="23dp"
    android:paddingRight="23dp"/>
```

**Activity**

```
      findViewById(R.id.testDialog).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  AlertDialog dialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this ,R.style.MaterialDialogDark)
                        .setTitle(R.string.label_title)
//                        .setMessage(R.string.label_mark_used_sure)
                        .setView(R.layout.material_text_alet_dialog)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.label_yes,(dialogInterface, i) -> {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Positive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        })

                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.label_no,(dialogInterface, i) -> {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Negative", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }).show();


                  TextView msgText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
                  msgText.setText(getString(R.string.not_authorized));



            }
        });
```